# What is the best way to query mongo with a large array coming from the client side?

Tags: mongodb, grails, pagination

On the client side of my application I have a JSON array containing a list of different locations.

```
Example : ["India" , "Spain" , "Chile"]
```

This array could get fairly big. Easily over 10k entries.

I need to query mongodb using this array to find all of the records in a collection where the location field matches can be found in the array.

Example documents :

```
{ 
   name : "Jim",
   location : "India"
}
{
   name : "Jane",
   location : "Spain"
}
```

As both Jim and Janes locations are in the array they will need to be passed back to the client.

I've been using the $in operator like so :

```
 document.find(location : [$in : ["India", "Spain" , "Chile"])
```

and its been working fine but I'm worried that there may be a better way. **My issue is that the array is being passed from the client based on user input. It could be very very large**. The amount of users being passed back from the query could also be very  large so I'm using **pagination** to display them. Therefore everytime I want to go to a new page **I'm passing the huge array back to the server for the query**. It is terribly inefficient but I'm not sure that there is a better way of doing it.

Does a anyone have any experience with this sort of issue?

Comment: I don't know about the "find" method in Grails you use, but usually it returns cursor. So while pagination you don't need to send query every time to server. At least these two articles have an examaple of cursors http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/get-json-from-grails-mongo-gorm/ http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/get-json-from-grails-mongo-gorm/

Comment: But the array being used in the query will be different so I think I'll have to send it every time.